# How to set the page size to Envelope size with Landscape orientation?

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have problem on creating .pdf file with the Page settings as Envelope ,landscape format.

Here is my Code to convert the asp page into pdf in Itextsharp

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Receipt.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
bind_Data();
this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
//here i need to set Pagesize as Envelope.
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

i googled it but i couldn't find Envelope size.How do i set the page size as Envelope ,Landscape in dynamically

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an A4 document in landscape format with this line:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
```

If you want to create a document in envelope format, you shouldn't create an A4 page, instead you should do this:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(envelope, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
```

In this line, `envelope` is an object of type `Rectangle`.

There is no such thing as **the** envelope size. There are different envelope sizes to choose from: http://www.paper-papers.com/envelope-size-chart.html

For instance, if you want to create a page with the size of a [6-1/4 Commercial Envelope](http://www.paper-papers.com/6-14-Commercial-Envelopes-24lb-WHITE-WOVE-35-x-6.html), then you need to create a rectangle that measures 6 by 3.5 inch. The measurement system in PDF doesn't use inches, but user units. By default, 1 user unit = 1 point, and 1 inch = 72 points.

Hence you'd define the `envelope` variable like this:

```
Rectangle envelope = new Rectangle(432, 252);
```

Because:

```
6 inch x 72 points = 432 points (the width)
3.5 inch x 72 points = 252 points (the height)
```

If you want a different envelope type, you have to do the calculations of the dimensions of that envelope format.

Comment: Thank you so much sir,its Clear ,is it possible to add the border align size   
Border :Left 0.75,right 0.75,Top 0.16,Bottom 0.236 in Internet Explorer. it doesn't accept Decimal values Respected to x1,y1,...
 
Guide me right way sir

Comment: That is a **totally different** question. You should not hijack the comments of your own question (to which a correct answer was given, unfortunately, you didn't *accept* that correct answer) to ask a *different* question. I will not answer this in a comment section.

Comment: im new to this sir .i accept its a best one.can you tell me whats meaning for this line?  Document pdfDoc = new Document(envelope, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);     what is 10f,10f,100f,0f ? is this border?

Comment: Those values are margins. They define the area where iText will not print anything when you use `Document.add()`