# How to set a default zoom of 100% using itext java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am creating a pdf file using iText. But its opening in different zoom percentage in each time. How to set the default zoom to 100% using java ?  I am creating the PDF document using the below code :

```
        String fileName = "Dashboard.pdf";
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                + fileName + "\"");
        Document my_pdf_report = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, response.getOutputStream());
        my_pdf_report.open();
```

Because I need to generate a Save as Popup also. So is it possible to use

```
        PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ,
                0, reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 1f);
```

in my code . If it is possible how it can be done ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set zoom level to pdf using iTextSharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087786/how-to-set-zoom-level-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: Actually i am creating the file like this: `String fileName = "Dashboard.pdf";
   response.setContentType("application/pdf");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
     + fileName + "\"");
   Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
   PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, response.getOutputStream());` Because i need to generate Save as popup also. So is it possible to use `PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ,
        0, reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 1f);'  in the above code sample ?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my answer to this question: [How to set zoom level to pdf using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087786/how-to-set-zoom-level-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

In answer to this question, I have written the [AddOpenAction](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/AddOpenAction) example (which is using Java). This example opens a PDF with a zoom factor of 75%. You need a PDF that opens with a zoom factor of 100%. This means that you need to adapt the following line:

```
PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ,
    0, reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 0.75f);
```

Like this:

```
PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ,
    0, reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 1f);
```

With the 0.75 replaced by 1, the zoom factor is no longer 75% but 100%.

Another difference with your situation, is that you are creating a PDF from scratch (as you explain in a comment). You have:

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, response.getOutputStream());
```

You should replace this with:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, response.getOutputStream());
```

Now you can do:

```
writer.setOpenAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer));
```

From another comment, we learn that you aren't aware of the page size of the PDFs you are creating. Please take a look at my answer to this question: [How to set the page size to Envelope size with Landscape orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886909/how-do-i-set-page-size-as-envelope-landscape-in-itextsharp)

You are creating a `Document` like this:

```
Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
```

This means that you are creating pages with the default size: A4.

In this case, the height of a page is 842, so you can use:

```
PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 842, 1f);
```

Please read [the documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) when in doubt. For a full, working example, see [OpenAt100pct](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/OpenAt100pct). The resulting PDF, [open100pct.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/open100pct.pdf) opens at 100% in viewers that respect the `/OpenAction` functionality (not all of them do, but that's a viewer problem, not an iText or a PDF problem).

Comment: Actually i am creating the file like this: `String fileName = "Dashboard.pdf";
   response.setContentType("application/pdf");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
     + fileName + "\"");
   Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
   PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, response.getOutputStream());` Because i need to generate Save as popup also. So is it possible to use `   PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ,
        0, reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 1f);` in the above code sample ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to make a small change. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So I have to do it like this 
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
 PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, response.getOutputStream());
   PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ,
        0, reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 1f);PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, stamper.getWriter()); writer.setOpenAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer)); my_pdf_report.open(); Is it possible to provide a sample code ? Because for me its not working

Comment: Remove the `PdfReader` and `PdfStamper`. You are creating a PDF from scratch. Why are you suddenly introducing `PdfReader` and `PdfStamper`? Please take a closer look at my update: `writer.setOpenAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer));` There is no `stamper.getWriter()` there! You don't need `PdfStamper` in your case, you already have a `writer`.

Comment: But for this line 'PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ,
    0, reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight(), 1f);' I need a reader instance right ?

Comment: No you don't. I'll explain in another update to my question.

Comment: PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 842, 1f);
   writer.setOpenAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer)); So i have to put it before my_pdf_report.open(); Right ?

Comment: Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, response.getOutputStream());
   PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 842, 1f);
   writer.setOpenAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer));
   my_pdf_report.open(); This is my code . But iam getting an error

Comment: @MaheshNarayanan I get the impression that you are intentionally making fun of me in an attempt to waste my time. I am going to pretend being naive and I am going to write you a full *working* example, but please be aware that patience is a scarce good. What does the error say? You should switch the line that opens the document with the open action declaration.

Comment: @ Bruno Lowagie I was not trying to make fun of you. java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getPageReference(PdfWriter.java:1075)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(PdfAction.java:454) . I was getting this error.

Comment: Anyway now its working, i need to open the file before PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 842, 1f); I was opening the file after this line. So thanks for your help.

Comment: @MaheshNarayanan OK, so if it works, why don't you accept the answer?