# Set 8 1/2" x 12" itext page size

Tags: itext

I am using itext PDF, and I need to set PDF document size as German Std. Fanfold(8 1/2" x 12"),I don't know how set Inches In Itext document.

```
// Now I can set paper size as A4 but i need to set 8 1/2" x 12" or German Std. Fanfold size 
document(name: fileName,pageSize: PageSize.A4,leftMargin:8, rightMargin:8, topMargin:8, bottomMargin:3)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please do yourself a favor and [read the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886909/how-to-set-the-page-size-to-envelope-size-with-landscape-orientation)!

As explained in the [Getting started](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/getting-started) section, measurements are expressed in user units, and there are 72 user units in an inch, so:

```
8.5 inch x 72 points = 612 user units
12 inch x 72 points = 864 user units
```

So you need to create a rectangle like this:

```
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(612, 864);
```

and a document like this:

```
Document document = new Document(pagesize);
```

edited 1/25/2021

Comment: But I got error:    No such property: paperSize for class: com.itextpdf.text.PageSize

Comment: I need to Import anything ?

Comment: Well, if you create a `Document` with a custom page size, you don't need the `PageSize` class anywhere in your code, because you are using the `Rectangle` class. Remove `PageSize` from your code.

Comment: Also: why would you use a propery `paperSize`? That property doesn't exist. I don't mention it anywhere in my answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bruno Lowagie it works,  you are my online tutor

Comment: Yah your correct before that i was used PageSize.A4, so i just removed A4 and add PageSize.paperSize. Now i fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121741/discussion-between-kamal-kannan-and-bruno-lowagie).